# Why does printf("%d", ~0) output -1?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

Why does `printf("%d", ~0);` yield a value of `-1`? Shouldn't it be `1` since the `~` operator converts each 1-bit into a 0-bit and vice versa?

From what I understand is `0000` will be negated to `1111`.

Comment: try printf("%x", ~0); It will print ff.. which means it negates every bit so
0000000000000000 is converted to 1111111111111111.
as per logic if first bit is 1 then it is treated as negative number.
hence -1

Comment: Read about how integers are internally stored as [two's complements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement). Explains why binary all `1`s represents decimal `-1`.

Comment: C compilers don't handle single bits when using numeric literals. 0 is 0 in some amount of bits, for example 32. So ~0 will negate 32 bits, not just one. It doesn't matter if you write 0 or 00 or 000, it's always the same zero with 32 bits. If you write 1, it's 31 zeroes and a single 1 and negating that will again negate all 32 bits.

Comment: @tuyen le: Yes, `0000` is transformed to `1111`. But why did you expect binary `1111` bit-pattern to represent `1`???

Comment: I did not realize that 1111 represent -1 in two's complement. Because one's complement for 0001 is 1110. Everything is clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`~`** is a bitwise complement operator . `00000000` is flipped to `11111111`.

If you take `2's`complement of `1(00000001)` what you get is `11111111` which is to represent `-1` in binary.

Therefore the output is `-1`.

Comment: thanks, everything is clear now

Comment: @tuyenle That's good , cheers !!

Comment: thats why ~ is used in checking the return values status(whether it is positive or negative) from a function.

Answer (score 2):

Try to see the hex part of it.

```
printf("%x", ~0);
```

It will print `ffff` which means it negates every bit so `0000000000000000` is converted to `1111111111111111`. 
As per logic, if first bit is 1 then it is treated as negative number. 
hence `-1`.

Answer (score 2):

In C/C++, `~` is the bitwise complement operator. For any given bitwise-complementable object `x`, it'll flip all binary digits found in the raw representation of `x`. Thus, if an integer `x` is represent in binary as `0b00000000`, it'll become `0x11111111`.

### BUT!!!!!

The answer is *not* always `-1`. What happens is that there are two ways to represent negative numbers in existence, namely one's complement, and two's complement.

### One's complement

For any number `x`, `-x` is represented as the bitwise complement of `x`.

### Two's complement

For any number `x`, `-x` is represented as *one plus* the bitwise complement of `x`.

### The real world

Find me a (modern) system using one's complement and I give you a free cookie! The fact is that one's complement allows for such nonsenses as `-0`, and in fact, your code would render that on a one's complement machine.

**BTW**, as other answers have already posted, the actual **printing** (*not* internal representation) of a number may vary if it's casted (`unsigned`s just ignore the extra top bit and thus allow for twice range before overflowing).

Comment: The C standard also allows sign and magnitude to encode signed numbers..

Comment: @BillLynch: Find me a (modern) system using/doing that I give you (yet another) free cookie!

Comment: **Comment deleted because it was duplicated for no sane reason.**

Answer (score 2):

In 32-bit machine `0` represent as

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
```

As when you apply biwise [NOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT)(~) then it flip all bit then bit representation like be

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
```

which is `-1` representation of 2s complement.

Answer (score 1):

```
%d takes signed integer

different variations of same input

 Signed Value ~0 -1
UnSigned Value ~0 4294967295
Hex  Value ~0 ffffffff
Hex  Value ~0 FFFFFFFF
```

as you can see the signed bit is set and its nothing but 2's compliment of 1

as a rule

> ```
> -ve of n = (~n) + 1;
> ```

```
      complement of 5  is  -6 
 and  complement(5)+1  is   -5
```